# Can you put an if statement in a constructor in c++ to set up an object in a particular way?

Tags: c++

I have a class that will take in 4 parameters when an object is created for it. These are: a character, and 3 integers.

However, depending on what the character is, the object needs to be set up in a different way. e.g. if the character is 'T' then set all object parameters to 0 except for those given, but if the character is 'B' then set all the class parameters to 10 except for those given.

I'd like to do this at the point of the object's creation.

Ideally, I would overload the constructor like this:

```cpp
construct('B', int a, int b, int c) { //set up this way }
construct('T', int a, int b, int c) { //set up another way }
```

But I don't think that's allowed.

Is the best option to use an `if` statement inside the constructor?

```cpp
construct(char letter, int a, int b, int c) {
    if (letter == 'T'){
        //set up this way
    } else {
        //set up another way
    }
}
```

Or, is there a better way?

Edit: For clarification, I think I remember my coputing lecturer saying that it's good practice to keep construtors short (although I might be wrong). So partly my question is; does using the if statement approach make the constructor unnecessarily long?

Edit 2: Thanks for all the help, I spoke to a lecturer and he said the same thing. An if statement is reasonable, and it only would have been a problem if I'd put in a loop. The accepted answer works but I have decided to stick to what I know.

Comment: What you have with the if looks decent. You could split "this way" and "that way" into their own functions and call them from the constructor if things start looking ugly/complicated.

Comment: I would use different constructors and handle the if statement outside of the constructor

Comment: The problem as described here would reasonably be solved with `if`/`else`.  Perhaps you could [edit] the question to clarify what you mean by "janky" and "better".  If you are really asking if any solution is "better than janky", some clarity on what that means may be needed.

Comment: @user4581301 In the end I did exactly that, cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a discriminating token to distinguish which constructor you want to invoke.  Since, otherwise, the parameters are all of the same times in the example case.

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
public:
    enum B_token{ B };
    enum T_token{ T };
    Foo(B_token, int, int, int);
    Foo(T_token, int, int, int);

    int value;
};

Foo::Foo(B_token, int a, int b, int c) : value{a + b + c} {}
Foo::Foo(T_token, int a, int b, int c) : value{a * b * c} {}

int main() {
    auto b = Foo{Foo::B, 2, 3, 4};
    auto t = Foo{Foo::T, 2, 3, 4};
    std::cout << "b:" << b.value << "\n";
    std::cout << "t:" << t.value << "\n";
}
```

Comment: If you instead use `static constexpr enum struct B_token{} b_token{};`, that will simplify the user code a little bit.

Comment: Might want to use empty structs instead of enums.

Comment: Two very good suggestions!  One of them may be more suitable for Finno's situation.

Comment: "Tag dispatch" would be the name of the empty struct technique described in other comments.

Comment: @DrewDormann • Thanks, very timely! I was trying to think of what that was called. I use the private struct key **tag dispatch** with a class static function factory I usually call `Make`, to work around the `std::make_unique` or `std::make_shared` problem with non-public constructors.  (I'm on C++14.  Maybe there's a good way to `friend` those templates in C++17 or C++20.)